# Как подключить LoadScript?

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь использовать данный [плагин](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-load-script).
Файл main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './assets/tailwind.css'
import LoadScript from "vue-plugin-load-script";

createApp(App).use(LoadScript).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Однако, в консоли выводится ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$loadScript' of undefined. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема не в подключении а в использивании вы юзаете

```
this.$loadScript(<url>)
```

Попробуйте так:

```
Vue.loadScript(<url>)
```